# USB Ports Disconnect and Reconnect when light is ON

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a strange problem.. when I turn ON the lights in my room my USB ports disconnect and reconnect. And sometimes when I have my Mobile Phone near the computer and it rings it will act the same. I searched everywhere for an answer.. but with no success.

I bought a UPS device.. thinking it will solve my problem.. but it didn't. 
I re-installed the USB drivers.. 
I removed the "Allow this computer to turn off this device to save power" from the USB Root Hubs.
I checked my outlets with a multimeter to see if there are any fluctuations. There are non when I turn on the lights.
I checked the voltages from my motherboard to see if there are any changes. Non that I could observe.

I don't know what else to do.. I'm running out of options.  Please.. if someone could help me.. I would really appreciate it!!

Comment: More details on your computer? I'm guessing it's a desktop?

Comment: Since you've already checked the outlets, I'd try testing the output from the power supply when you turn the lights on or off.